# I am getting undefined when trying to return the date value from an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

JAVASCRIPT

I am just trying to returen the value of the date selected but it's coming back undefined.

```
var getDate = function() {              
    var bdinput = $('#bd.bdinput').val();
    var _this = bdinput;                    
    console.log(_this);

};

$("button.bdsubmit").click(function() {                         
    console.log(getDate());
})
```

HTML

```
<form id="bd">                  
<input name="BirthDate" class="bdinput" type="date" />
<button class="bdsubmit"  type="submit">Submit Date</button>
```

Comment: ``$('#bd.bdinput').value;`` should be ``$('#bd.bdinput').val()``;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get value of input not `.value`

```
var bdinput = $('#bd .bdinput').val();
                 // ^ also need space here
```

`$('#bd .bdinput')` will select element with class `bdinput` inside element with id `bd`.

`$('#bd.bdinput')` will select a element with id 'bd' and class `bdinput` (both id and class in one element)

---

If you want to do it with `.value`

```
var bdinput = $('#bd .bdinput')[0].value;
```

Or

```
var bdinput = $('#bd .bdinput').get(0).value;
```

Comment: Tried that and if I alert(getDate()); I get undefined.

Comment: @Paul Did you add space `$('#bd .bdinput').val();` in between `#bd` and `.bdinput` .

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple mistake.

```
var bdinput = $('#bd.bdinput').value;
```

should be:

```
var bdinput = $('#bd. bdinput').val();
```